# CSS Rules affecting other Objects

Tags: css

is it possible for a css rule (such as `#testobject1:hover  {}`) to have an effect on another object `#testobject2`?

Comment: How does your corresponding markup look like?

Comment: there is no markup yet, its an idea im playing around with to try to avoid using javascript for connecting object changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

The only way this could work is if `#testobject2` was a descendant of `#testobject1`:

```
<div id="testobject1">
  <div id="testobject2">
    Hello.
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS would then be:

```
#testobject1:hover #testobject2 {
  ...
}
```

Comment: in a test, it worked quite well. i set the position data to shift it over to where i wanted it. cheers

Comment: The reason it does this is because CSS doesn't travel *up* the DOM tree. *Only* down. Maybe in a few years the CSS people will be nice and implement this, but for now, this is best we've got...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you write something like:

```
#testobject1:hover, #testobject2:hover {}
```

or if `#testobject2` is a children of the `#testobject1` element and it inherits the properties declared in that CSS piece.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: does that mean if `#testobject1` is hovered over, `#testobject2` will change as well?

Comment: Yes, the comma list means it applies to all those properties.

Comment: No, in order to do that, `#testobject2` must be a children of `#testobject1` and the syntax is `#testobject1:hover #testobject2 { }`.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid your comment is incorrect: with the comma you just apply the same rule to both the elements, but if you hover the first one, the second one isn't affected at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if the 2nd element is a descendant of the first:

```
#testobject1:hover #testobject2 {}
```

This will cause the css of this rule to be applied to `#testobject2` only when `#testobject1` is hovered.

**EDIT:**  An Interesting use of this involves absolutely positioned elements.  You can have an element which is a descendant of another but visually does not appear within the other element at all.  The hover will still work.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2psw/

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, the only way to apply the same style to two different objects like you said is construct your style with more than one selectors. Like this:

```
#testobject1:hover, #testobject2 {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Not really.  CSS cascades down so as others have said if #testobject2 is a descendant of #testobject1 then it will inherit the attributes of #testobject1 unless they are overridden (and some attributes can't be)